# In Module 1 of my project has multiple classes. Those multiple classes are using different versions of projectA

Tags: java, maven

My project is a multi module project. In that, Module 1 has multiple classes and those multiple classes are using different versions of project A.

```
This is module1--->com.assign.print:printlog.value:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
```

Class1 is using ProjectA (com.print.assess:mns.pro:6.2) with version 6.2

Class2 is using ProjectA (com.print.assess:mns.pro:2.0) with version 2.0.

And this is giving dependency convergence error. How to resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is ProjectB misspelled and you meant ProjectA? (I'm assuming that from your title)

Comment: Yes. It was misspelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard Java problem.

You cannot have two different versions of the same dependency on your classpath.

You can try to work around this with the Maven shade plugin, but it is kind of hacky.

Better is to change your code that it works with the same version of the dependency.

Comment: I cannot change the code. Could you tell me how to use maven shade plugin in the module pom

Comment: What do you mean: You cannot change the code? It is your code that uses the different dependencies, why not resolve this?

Comment: The thing is I am using classes from external library which is using dependency version 2.0. So I cannot change that

Comment: You can try with https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/ but maybe you should try whether you find versions of your external libraries that work together with one version.